# How does OpenGL decide between using MAG_FILTER and MIN_Filter when accessing in shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, mipmaps

When configuring OpenGL with glTexParamteri(GL_Texture_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, ...) and glTexParamteri(GL_Texture_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, ...) how does OpenGL decide which filter to use when accessing a texture in shader with texture(...)?

My only guess it's that it is calculating the pixel footprint but since you could access the texture in either the fragment or vertex shader it can't know on which primitive what texture is projected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My only guess it's that it is calculating the pixel footprint

Yes, that's what it does. It will approximate the pixel footprint in the texture space by calcualting the derivatives of the texcoords with respect to the window space `x` and `y` direction, and it will approximate these derivatives by *finite differencing* in a 2x2 pixel quad, just like the [`dFdx` and `dFdy` GLSL functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dFdx.xhtml) are working. It will use the longer of the two partial derivative vectors as the size, and calculate the Level-Of-Detail value based on that.

> but since you could access the texture in either the fragment or vertex shader it can't know on which primitive what texture is projected.

Correct, that's why the [GLSL specification,
 (Version 4.60)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf) states the following in the beginning of section *8.9 Texture Functions*:

> Texture lookup functions are available in all shading stages. However, automatic level of detail is
>   computed only for fragment shaders. Other shaders operate as though the base level of detail were
>   computed as zero

Comment: Understanding dFdx and dFdy helped me alot, especially this [site:](http://www.aclockworkberry.com/shader-derivative-functions/) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some (ie: most) GLSL texture accessing functions say that they require "implicit derivatives". All such functions only work entirely:

1. [In the fragment shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Texture_lookup_in_shader_stages).
2. Within [uniform control flow of the FS](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Non-uniform_flow_control).

If you call a texture access function that requires implicit derivatives in a non-fragment shader, then it will only access from the base mipmap level. However, if you're in a fragment shader but outside of uniform control flow, then all such functions have undefined behavior.

So if you're not in a fragment shader, you either want to access from the base mipmap level (in which case, `MAG_FILTER` applies), or you want to use functions that explicitly provide the values used for doing interpolation: `Lod` (where you [explicitly say what mipmap level(s) you fetch from](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Lod_texture_access)), `Grad` (where you [explicitly specify derivatives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Gradient_texture_access) used to decide where the pixel footprint is), or any of the `texelFetch` or `textureGather` functions (which don't do interpolation at all).